# Custom Class not displaying echo

Tags: php

I have been trying to write a class to be used for displaying errors and error log.

```
class CError {

//Error Logging

var $Log;

public function Log($Comment, $Detail = ""){

    $Log .= $Comment . "\n";

    if ($Detail !== ""){
        $Log .= "--" . $Detail . "--\n";
    }
}

public function Clear_Log(){
    $Log = "";
}

public function Display_Log(){
    echo $this->Log;
}

//Error Display

var $ErrorCode = array(
    0 => "0: No Error Code found, so either you got here by some rogue code or ...",
    1 => "1: General Error, if you are here something went wrong",
    2 => "2: Invalid information provided",
    3 => "3: Alternate path taken, check message for details",
    42 => "42: Here is your answer, but do you know the question?",
    50 => "50: You messed with the Creepers without your Diamond Sword, didn't you",
    9001 => "9001: Its over 9000... or more likely a value used was to large",
    418 => "418: I'm a Teapot, found the error that drove you crazy"
);

public function Error($Error = 0, $ShowLog = false){        

    if ($Error === ""){
        $Error = 0;
    }

    foreach ($ErrorCode as $key => $value){
        if($key == $Error){
            echo "<h3 style='color:red'>" . $value . "</h3><br />";
        }
    }

    if($ShowLog == true){
        echo $this->Log;
    }
}
```

}

This is how I use the error class

```
include 'CError.php';
$Error = new CError;

$Error->Log("Email is Required");
$Error->Display_Log();
$Error->Error(2,true);
```

The problem is, nothing is displayed when used. It is skipped I think but not sure. I do not have access to the error logs for the server so I do not know if an error is being produced or not but the code will run through to the exit points in my main code(irrelevant to the class)

--EDIT--

The answers that tell to change $Log with $this->Log has fixed the issue with the $Log variable. It still has not fixed the issue with the error code array being displayed in the foreach loop.

--EDIT--

I solved the issue by adding $this->ErrorCode to the foreach loop.

Comment: What PHP version are you writing this for?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: I am not sure the exact version but it is php 5. The servers are hosted by netfirms.ca using apache on linux(not sure the flavor)

Comment: Why are you using the `var` keyword?

Comment: Something I was taught by my teachers. But I have the code working now. But thank you.

Comment: Tell your teachers to stop teaching old stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access class variable like `$this->Log()` in `Log` and `Clear_Log()` functions.

Try:

```
public function Log($Comment, $Detail = ""){

    $this->Log .= $Comment . "\n";

    if ($Detail !== ""){
        $this->Log .= "--" . $Detail . "--\n";
    }
}

public function Clear_Log(){
    $this->Log = "";
}
```

Comment: This has helped part of my issue. Thank You.

Comment: This has been useful but not a full answer. I will accept this answer if no other helps the issue. Again thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `$this->Log` in methods `Log` and `Clear_Log`, like you access it in `Display_Log`. And you just access a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

you're using the name Log for both function as well as variable. try changing the name for any one.